# Clicking on specific apps in Microsoft store crashes the store instantly. Why?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, store

I have noticed that Microsoft Store crashes (force close) when I search and click on the app icon. This problem does only happen with certain apps for example Audiobooks from audible and Scan - QR code and barcode reader. Why does this happen?

- OS: Windows 10 Mobile
- Phone: Lumia 640 XL

Comment: soft reset the phone, check if you any update for the store.

Comment: I'm already on the latest final build. All my apps are updated. I have done  a hard reset few weeks ago. I am not gonna do any resets again after that hard reset.

Comment: Is this a public general build, or an insider build?

Comment: Public general 10.0.10586.494

Comment: @mms911 I am running the same build and I don't face this problem with the apps you mentioned. Is there any pending updates on the mentioned apps? What happens when you open the app from the URL link? In case you haven't tried that yet try it now - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/audiobooks-from-audible/9wzdncrfj1cr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved by changing the device language from Arabic to English.